# Thread updates not available for selected client

Tags: android, eclipse, debugging

When i open the ddms perspective i get thos message------thread updates not available for selected client.. It also tells me  to use toolbar button to enable-----But i see no such button. What could be wrong. Please help out.

Answer (score 62):

In the DDMS perspective you should have the "Devices" window to the left (by standard). Otherwise open it by going to the menu Window -> Show View -> Other. In the popup navigate to Android -> Devices and press OK.

The button (you can't find) is the fifth from the left side in the Devices window, which has the same icon as the Threads window you get the error in. Press it and it should update and you can see the threads.

Further details and pictures have [a look here](http://spacetech.dk/android-thread-updates-not-enabled-for-selected-client-use-toolbar-button-to-enable.html)